# Strange MySQL Issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

So I setup a table using mysql query browser, and now i'm trying to fill it up. But no  matter what I do, it says "created account succesfully", but nothing ever gets added to the database!

The code I have is below:

`

```
            if($connection)
            {
                $out =
                    "<p>Please wait while we process your request.</p>";

                mysql_select_db(
                    "accounts",
                    $connection
                );

                    // Generate Account Number.
                    $AccountNumber = rand(17000, 904870);

                    // Set Account Values.
                    $GenuineUser = 0;
                    $VerifiedAdvertiser = 0;
                    $DateOfBirth =
                        $_POST["bmoth"] . "/" . $_POST["bday"] . "/" . $_POST["byear"];

                    // MD5 the Account ID.
                    $AccountID = md5($_POST["AccountID"]);
                // Create Advertiser Account.
                mysql_query(
                    "INSERT INTO accounts.advertisers (
                        'Account Number',
                        'Account ID',
                        'First Name',
                        'Last Name',
                        'Date Of Birth',
                        'Email Address',
                        'Phone Number',
                        'Street Address',
                        'City',
                        'Zip Code',
                        'State',
                        'Country',
                        'Genuine User',
                        'Verified Advertiser') VALUES (
                            '".$AccountNumber."',
                            '".$_POST["AccountID"]."',
                            '".$_POST["FirstName"]."',
                            '".$_POST["LastName"]."',
                            '".$DateOfBirth."',
                            '".$_POST["EmailAddress"]."',
                            '".$_POST["PhoneNumber"]."',
                            '".$_POST["StreetAddress"]."',
                            '".$_POST["City"]."',
                            '".$_POST["ZipCode"]."',
                            '".$_POST["State"]."',
                            '".$_POST["Country"]."',
                            '".$GenuineUser."',
                            '".$VerifiedAdvertiser."')
                ");

                // Setup Advertisement Table.


                // Assume account created successfully.
                $out =
                    "<p>Advertiser Account created.</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                die('Oh, @#%#!: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_close($connection);
        }
        else
        { 
                                    // else, display form. 
                           } ?>
```

`

Could somebody kindly help me sort this out, please? I'd appreciate any help at all.

Thank you

**update**
So, I've managed to figure out what was going to, thanks to all your advice :) As it turns out, it wasn't working because I was using spaces inbetween the Column Names (i.e. Account ID should be AccountID). So I just removed spaces from the table columns, and also from the php code.

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: put the query in separate variable, print/echo it and try to run the query from phpmyadmin or from the mysql console.

Comment: Also, check for errors.  In a pinch you could do `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())`; which will then print the error out to you.  Also note that you have massive [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities in your code that you posted.  You really should be using prepared statements, or at very least [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on any untrusted input that goes into your queries...

Comment: Have updated answer to explain what was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to figure out what was going to, thanks to all your advice :) As it turns out, it wasn't working because I was using spaces inbetween the Column Names (i.e. Account ID should be AccountID). So I just removed spaces from the table columns, and also from the php code.

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You really should be checking for errors in your query. Even something as basic as:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Any time you do a mysql function you should check for errors, or have a method of catching exceptions (if using an applicable interface, since the default mysql functions don't throw exceptions).

It could be messing up on a few points.

Also, as a hint, `sprintf` works wonderfully if you're writing queries out.

Comment: Thanks for that! I got an error saying to check for valid syntax at line 2, so then I realised that maybe it was the single quote on the top part of the query (before VALUES), So I removed the single quotes. Then, I got another error, same thing: **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Number, Account ID, First Name, Last Name, Date ' at line 2"**

Comment: Could it be possible that it's because of the spaces inbetween the Names (i.e. Account ID etc)?

Comment: Problem solved! It WAS the spaces inbetween the Column names. That's so strange because MySQL Query Browser let me use spaces, just like a spreadsheet. Oh well, now I know. Now that it's working, time to make it secure!!! :) Thanks for helping, Codeacula! :-)

Comment: You mean, use ` instead of '? :) Thanks, ircmaxell!

Comment: The Query Browser will correct it for you, obviously. And use \` instead of ', but I would also make sure to check for ` as part of your SQL sanitizing and handle as desired, since 'mysql_escape_string()' isn't aware of it.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_escape_string`!  It's deprecated and doesn't work correctly.  Use `mysql_real_escape_string`.  And it doesn't matter if it knows about `\``, since the result will be put inside of quotes, so it won't be parsed as an identifier token anyway...

Comment: I was lazy and left out real. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your SQL query. You're getting "Account created" because you're not testing for it.